# Is there a WebView library that implements the security patch from Android 4.4?

Tags: android, security, webview

Very recently, we all heard about the security hole in WebView for any Android version below KitKat. Knowing that Google isn't planning on patching it, does anyone know about an alternative implementation of WebView that fixes this security flaw for all versions of Android?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) it seems to do what you need.

From what I understand this is more geared towards hybrid/cordova based apps. Beware that this will increase the size of your application (10-15 MB)